# App launches on wrong activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launch

It seems like my Android app starts on the wrong activity.

The important part from AndroidManifest.xml:

"MainActivity" should be the activity that is started on app launch:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="AnotherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //display into log that THIS activity is started
        Log.d("tag", "MainActivity");

        //start async task to install the database on first startup
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show([params...]);
        new InstallDatabaseTask().execute(this);
}

/**
 * 1. Installs and initializes the database.
 * 2. Opens another activity.
 */
private class InstallDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            progressDialog.show();

            //open database so it can be installed
            MyOpenHelper helper = new MyOpenHelper((Context) params[0]);
            helper.getWritableDatabase().close();

            //dismiss progress dialog
            MainActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();

            //start another activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
            ((Context)params[0]).startActivity(intent);

            return null;
        }
}
```

AnotherActivity:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //just make sure this activity was started
        Log.d("tag", "another activity started");   
    }
```

But the log only displays "another activity started".

Comment: i think you must get crash because you async task has issues

Comment: But it does not seem like anything crashes. Do not have any errors in the output. But, the task runs. And database is installed.

Comment: have you tried @autobot_101 suggesstion

Comment: I did, as I answered to his post

Comment: is AnotherActivity being launched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code i understood that android is launching the correct activity.

But in your oncreate method you are calling async task so as soon as main activity creates it launches async task and in your async task you are calling below lines

```
//start another activity
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
((Context)params[0]).startActivity(intent);
```

so as soon as async task do its task it launches another activity. so you are assuming that android is launching wrong activity. But internally you are launching the activity and in your your async is completed in just few micro seconds so you are assuming that wrong activity is launched..

Comment: In the lines:

`MyOpenHelper helper = new MyOpenHelper((Context) params[0]);

helper.getWritableDatabase().close();`

the application is installing the database. Afterwards, the activity is called.So that shouldn't be the problem. And the app did not print "MainActivity" into the log, as it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access progress dialog from `doInBackground()` method (and others UI widgets) from a thread wich is not the UI thread. You should put that on `onPostExecute()`.

Something like:

```
private class InstallDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        progressDialog.show();

        //open database so it can be installed
        MyOpenHelper helper = new MyOpenHelper((Context) params[0]);
        helper.getWritableDatabase().close();



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

        //dismiss progress dialog
                    MainActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();

                    //start another activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
                    ((Context)params[0]).startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

I think that you need to declare the parameters when you extend AsyncTask.

I'm not sure if this solve your problem, but is a hint...

Comment: Thanks, changed it, but as you said, this did not solve my problem.

Comment: And for a long time, it worked that way - don't know why it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

And one thing, the AnotherActivity you declared in Manifest file got problem, isn't it ?

```
<activity
    android:name="AnotherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

I think it should have a dot .  like

> android:name=".AnotherActivity"

Comment: Nope. I suggest the "dot" only stands for the default directory of the app, although, I changed it with no result. It doesn't work yet.

Answer (score -1):

In the manifest, make sure that the activity that is launching instead of the main activity is set to default.

category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.game.test.DIRECTOR" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

So it won't launch as the main. Also check your intent filters in the manifest to see if they are correct or present.

Comment: category.DEFAULT prevents the icon from showing up in the Apps grid.  There are cases when this is throwing out the baby with the bath water.